# python 3.x need help spliting 1 text file into 4 dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Can anyone help me with an issue i am having? i am trying to wright some code that will let a user select specific files called diarys then compare it to there current skill levels, each file has a easy, medium, hard, and elite section that i want to put in separate dictionary's, i can get it to print the correct info from the whole file but i cant figure out how to split it up into 4 separate dictionaries

```
# shows all osrs diarys 
def diary_selection():
    diary_options = {
    0 : 'ardougne', 1 : 'desert', 2 : 'falador', 3 : 'fremennik', 4 : 'kandarin',
    5 : 'lumbridge', 6 : 'morytania', 7 : 'varrock', 8 : 'western', 9 : 'wilderness'
    }
    print(diary_options)

# if not a correct number gives prompt to retry  
    while True:
        try:
            d_sel = int(input ("\nType in the number next to the diary: "))
            diary_select = d_sel

            if not (0 < diary_select > 9):
                print('option is valid')
                break
            else:
                print(" invalid option.")
                diary_selection()

        except ValueError:
            print(" invalid option, numbers only, please try again.")


# gets the name of the diary acording to what number was pressed
    current_diary = diary_options.get(diary_select)

#creats a filename for spicific diary        
    diary_file_name = str((current_diary + "_diary.txt"))
    print (diary_file_name,"\n")

#searches for file name in folder ./diary_requirements     
    f = open("./diary_requirements/"+diary_file_name,"r")
    file_contents = f.read()


    return file_contents
```

the files i am trying to manipulate are structured inside a txt file in this format with easy,medium,hard,elite levels.

```
easy_levels = {
"Attack" : 0
, "Defense" : 0
, "Strength" : 0
, "Hitpoints": 0
, "Range" : 30
, "Prayer" : 0
, "Magic" : 0
, "Cooking" : 0
, "Woodcutting" : 0
, "Fletching" : 20
, "Fishing" : 0
, "Firemaking" : 0
, "Crafting" : 0
, "Smithing" : 0
, "Mining" : 15
, "Herblore" : 0
, "Agility" : 0
, "Thieving" : 0
, "Slayer" : 0
, "Farming" : 0
, "Runecrafting" : 0
, "Hunting": 9
, "Construction" : 0
,
}
medium_levels = {
"Attack" : 0
, "Defense" : 0
, "Strength" : 0
, "Hitpoints": 0
, "Range" : 30
, "Prayer" : 0
, "Magic" : 0
, "Cooking" : 42
, "Woodcutting" : 35
, "Fletching" : 5
, "Fishing" : 46
, "Firemaking" : 35
, "Crafting" : 0
, "Smithing" : 0
, "Mining" : 40
, "Herblore" : 0
, "Agility" : 37
, "Thieving" : 0
, "Slayer" : 0
, "Farming" : 0
, "Runecrafting" : 0
, "Hunting": 31
, "Construction" : 0
,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the only part you struggle is how to fill out four dictionaries given a file with the structure you described.

If you are sure that those files will not be altered by anything/anyone other than you, and you are okay with using unsafe & dirty code, you can just do:

```
exec(file_contents)
```

What this does is, since the content of your file structure is already valid python, it executes it in the scope it's been called. So after executing it, you have access to variables `easy_levels, medium_levels, hard_levels, elite_levels` in the scope you called it. *Please note that* this assumes you have those variables correctly defined in any diary you try to access, if the variables defined per diary may change, you should use a safer method (or an ugly quick hack accessing locals()).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
import imp
from pprint import pprint

# shows all osrs diarys 
def diary_selection():
    diary_options = {
    0 : 'ardougne', 1 : 'desert', 2 : 'falador', 3 : 'fremennik', 4 : 'kandarin',
    5 : 'lumbridge', 6 : 'morytania', 7 : 'varrock', 8 : 'western', 9 : 'wilderness'
    }
    print(diary_options)

    # if not a correct number gives prompt to retry  
    while True:
        try:
            d_sel = int(input ("\nType in the number next to the diary: "))
            diary_select = d_sel

            if diary_select in diary_options:
                print('option is valid')
                break
            else:
                print(" invalid option.")
                #diary_selection()

        except ValueError:
            print(" invalid option, numbers only, please try again.")


    # gets the name of the diary acording to what number was pressed
    current_diary = diary_options.get(diary_select)

    #creats a filename for spicific diary        
    diary_file_name = str((current_diary + "_diary.txt"))
    print (diary_file_name,"\n")

    #searches for file name in folder ./diary_requirements     
    #f = open("./diary_requirements/"+diary_file_name,"r")
    #file_contents = f.read()
    #return file_contents

    foo = imp.load_source('userInfo', os.getcwd() + '/diary_requirements/' + diary_file_name)
    print('{}\nEasy levels\n{}'.format('-'*40, '-'*40))
    pprint(foo.easy_levels)
    print('{}\nMediyum levels\n{}'.format('-'*40, '-'*40))
    pprint(foo.medium_levels)

diary_selection()
```

---

Output (python ):

```
{0: 'ardougne', 1: 'desert', 2: 'falador', 3: 'fremennik', 4: 'kandarin', 5: 'lumbridge', 6: 'morytania', 7: 'varrock', 8: 'western', 9: 'wilderness'}

Type in the number next to the diary: 6
option is valid
morytania_diary.txt 

----------------------------------------
Easy levels
----------------------------------------
{'Agility': 0,
 'Attack': 0,
 'Construction': 0,
 'Cooking': 0,
 'Crafting': 0,
 'Defense': 0,
 'Farming': 0,
 'Firemaking': 0,
 'Fishing': 0,
 'Fletching': 20,
 'Herblore': 0,
 'Hitpoints': 0,
 'Hunting': 9,
 'Magic': 0,
 'Mining': 15,
 'Prayer': 0,
 'Range': 30,
 'Runecrafting': 0,
 'Slayer': 0,
 'Smithing': 0,
 'Strength': 0,
 'Thieving': 0,
 'Woodcutting': 0}
----------------------------------------
Mediyum levels
----------------------------------------
{'Agility': 37,
 'Attack': 0,
 'Construction': 0,
 'Cooking': 42,
 'Crafting': 0,
 'Defense': 0,
 'Farming': 0,
 'Firemaking': 35,
 'Fishing': 46,
 'Fletching': 5,
 'Herblore': 0,
 'Hitpoints': 0,
 'Hunting': 31,
 'Magic': 0,
 'Mining': 40,
 'Prayer': 0,
 'Range': 30,
 'Runecrafting': 0,
 'Slayer': 0,
 'Smithing': 0,
 'Strength': 0,
 'Thieving': 0,
 'Woodcutting': 35}
```